# How to display comparison of 2 products with similarities

Tags: website-design, design, interface, html, web

I am in the following situation.

**Requirements:**

A web-based *functional* configuration-tool for 2 of our systems shall be created, whereas the *financial advantage* of **System A** over **System B** should be shown alongside with the built-in components (so as kinda table).
The user (mostly internal sales people) selects the appropiate configuration (radio buttons, text boxes, nothing special), and the built-in components should be shown depending on those configurations.

**The problem:**

*Layout-Space*:
Since the comparison should be in focus of the user, I cannot simply place 2 tables showing the components and their costs among themselves, since the user would have to scroll down for **System B** and cannot directly see the price advantage in detail.

*Info: The 2 systems consist of ~ 6 components, whereas they share 3 of them*.

I just graduated from grammar school and make an internship, please have indulgence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to show side-by-side comparisons for both features and prices, but I could see you setting up a "configurator" type page where as the user selects features, they are added to the two side-by-side columns and a total price  is shown at the top for each (and possibly an item-by-item price in line). Picture something like this, but with checkboxes (or something) stacked on the side with each feature, to be added or removed:

[image]

Very simple example, without more details on your project, but a start (I MAY have time to mock something up later).